# Concat two 2D tensors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I have a simple enough TensorFlow operation I need to execute, but I can't think of how to do it.

Currently, I have my data in a Tensor of the following format:

```
[[a0], [a1], [a2], ...]
```

I would like to convert that data into the following format:

```
[[1-a0, a0], [1-a1, a1], [1-a2, a2], ...]
```

There is probably a really simple solution that I lack the vocabulary to discover - would appreciate if I could be directed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [**`tf.concat`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat):

```
tf.concat([1 - x, x], axis=1)
# <tf.Tensor 'concat:0' shape=(3, 2) dtype=int32>
```